# Unable to store timestamp in Dynamo DB using Nodejs 16 version Lambda

Tags: aws-lambda, amazon-dynamodb, aws-sdk-nodejs

I am unable to store timestamp  in Dynamo DB using Node JS Lambda. i am new to Node JS.

while run the test case, it was stored. but while trigger this lambda function getting error.

i was try to insert below timestamp

LastUpdateTimestamp
The date and time this contact was last updated, in UTC time.

**Type: String (yyyy-mm-ddThh:mm:ssZ)**

```
// Copyright Amazon.com, Inc. or its affiliates. All Rights Reserved.
// SPDX-License-Identifier: MIT-0
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    
    var surveyResults = {};
    var data = event.Details.ContactData.Attributes;    // extract the contact attributes from the Amazon Connect event
    
    Object.keys(data).forEach(element => {
       if (element.startsWith("survey_result_")) {
           surveyResults[element] = { S: data[element] };
       }
    });
    
    var params = {
        TableName: process.env.TABLE,
        Item: {
            contactId: { S: event.Details.ContactData.ContactId},
            date: { S: event.Details.ContactData.LastUpdateTimestamp},
            surveyId: { S: event.Details.ContactData.Attributes.surveyId },
            ...surveyResults
        }
    }
    
    try {
        await ddb.putItem(params).promise();    // write the object to the DynamoDB table
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('OK'),
    };
    
    return response;
};
```

**Test Data:**

```
{
  "Name": "ContactFlowEvent",
  "Details": {
    "ContactData": {
      "Attributes": {
        "surveyId": "123456",
        "survey_result_1": "4",
        "survey_result_2": "5"
      },
      "Channel": "VOICE",
      "ContactId": "5ca32fbd-8f92-46af-92a5-6b0f970f0efe",
      "LastUpdateTimestamp": "2023-02-14T06:52:29Z",
      "CustomerEndpoint": {
        "Address": "+11234567890",
        "Type": "TELEPHONE_NUMBER"
      },
      "InitialContactId": "5ca32fbd-8f92-46af-92a5-6b0f970f0efe",
      "InitiationMethod": "API",
      "InstanceARN": "arn:aws:connect:us-east-1:123456789012:instance/9308c2a1-9bc6-4cea-8290-6c0b4a6d38fa",
      "MediaStreams": {
        "Customer": {
          "Audio": {
            "StartFragmentNumber": "91343852333181432392682062622220590765191907586",
            "StartTimestamp": "1565781909613",
            "StreamARN": "arn:aws:kinesisvideo:us-east-1:123456789012:stream/connect-contact-a3d73b84-ce0e-479a-a9dc-5637c9d30ac9/1565272947806"
          }
        }
      },
      "PreviousContactId": "5ca32fbd-8f92-46af-92a5-6b0f970f0efe",
      "Queue": null,
      "SystemEndpoint": {
        "Address": "+11234567890",
        "Type": "TELEPHONE_NUMBER"
      }
    },
    "Parameters": {}
  }
}
```

**Error:**

```
2023-02-15T14:10:26.426Z    94fad25e-bcdb-443b-95c0-47640bfaba34    INFO    ValidationException: Supplied AttributeValue is empty, must contain exactly one of the supported datatypes
    at Request.extractError (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/protocol/json.js:52:27)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:106:20)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:78:10)
    at Request.emit (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:686:14)
    at Request.transition (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:22:10)
    at AcceptorStateMachine.runTo (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:14:12)
    at /var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/state_machine.js:26:10
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:38:9)
    at Request.<anonymous> (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/request.js:688:12)
    at Request.callListeners (/var/runtime/node_modules/aws-sdk/lib/sequential_executor.js:116:18) {
  code: 'ValidationException',
  time: 2023-02-15T14:10:26.328Z,
  requestId: 'F5JJOCF20D507JCFRO7FEMAH6VVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG',
  statusCode: 400,
  retryable: false,
  retryDelay: 15.458319111471575
}
```

Comment: Log the value of `Item` before the putItem call. What does it contain? And which attributes are part of the primary key and what are their types (pk=contactId and sk=date, both strings?)

Comment: Whats contained in `...surveyResults`? Can you print its value?

Comment: Hi below are the values of surveyResults
 "survey_result_1": "4",
        "survey_result_2": "5"

Comment: Hi primary key is ContactID. and both ContactID and date are strings

Comment: But in my table only primary key(pk). No sort key. I want to add date coloumn once lamda is triggered

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    
    var surveyResults = {};
    var data = event.Details.ContactData.Attributes;    // extract the contact attributes from the Amazon Connect event
    
    Object.keys(data).forEach(element => {
       if (element.startsWith("survey_result_")) {
           surveyResults[element] = { S: data[element] };
       }
    });
    var contact_params = {
  ContactId: event.Details.ContactData.InitialContactId, /* required */
  InstanceId: 'paste your instance id' /* required */
};
var connect = new AWS.Connect();
console.log('describeContact');
/*connect.describeContact(contact_params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});*/
const attributes = await connect.describeContact(contact_params).promise();
console.log(attributes)
console.log(typeof attributes.Contact.LastUpdateTimestamp)
var agent_params = {
  InstanceId: 'paste your instance id', /* required */
  UserId: attributes.Contact.AgentInfo.Id /* required */
  
};
const agent = await connect.describeUser(agent_params).promise();
let agent_username = "";
if(agent_username != null){
agent_username = agent.User.Username; 
}
console.log(agent)
const months = ['January', 'February', 'March', 'April', 'May', 'June', 'July', 'August', 'September', 'October', 'November', 'December'];
    var params = {
        TableName: process.env.TABLE,
        Item: {
            contactId: { S: event.Details.ContactData.ContactId},
            surveyId: { S: event.Details.ContactData.Attributes.surveyId },
            date: { S: attributes.Contact.LastUpdateTimestamp.toLocaleDateString()},
            time: { S: attributes.Contact.LastUpdateTimestamp.toLocaleTimeString()},
            agentname: {S: agent_username},
            monthnumber: { S: attributes.Contact.LastUpdateTimestamp.toLocaleDateString().split("/")[0]},
            monthname: { S: months[parseInt(attributes.Contact.LastUpdateTimestamp.toLocaleDateString().split("/")[0])-1]},
            ...surveyResults
        }
    }
    
    
    
    try {
        await ddb.putItem(params).promise();    // write the object to the DynamoDB table
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('OK'),
    };
    
    return response;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

You state that `...surveyResults` contains the following:

```
"survey_result_1": "4", 
"survey_result_2": "5"
```

This is not DynamoDB JSON. You need to modify the values to suit the correct format as you have done with the other values.

Comment: Yes, you want Dynamo DB Json. I will provide test json. Kindly please help me how add time stamp from above code. Date is string here. Please help

Comment: Hi , Below is the sample dynamoDB JSON
{
  "contactId": {
    "S": "5e57ea33-d19c-44af-879a-4d08812c8ef4"
  },
  "surveyId": {
    "S": "123456"
  },
  "survey_result_1": {
    "S": "1"
  },
  "survey_result_2": {
    "S": "1"
  }
}

Answer (score 0):

```
const AWS = require('aws-sdk');
const ddb = new AWS.DynamoDB();

exports.handler = async (event) => {
    
    var surveyResults = {};
    var data = event.Details.ContactData.Attributes;    // extract the contact attributes from the Amazon Connect event
    
    Object.keys(data).forEach(element => {
       if (element.startsWith("survey_result_")) {
           surveyResults[element] = { S: data[element] };
       }
    });
    var contact_params = {
  ContactId: event.Details.ContactData.InitialContactId, /* required */
  InstanceId: 'place your instance id' /* required */
};
var connect = new AWS.Connect();
console.log('describeContact');
/*connect.describeContact(contact_params, function(err, data) {
  if (err) console.log(err, err.stack); // an error occurred
  else     console.log(data);           // successful response
});*/
const attributes = await connect.describeContact(contact_params).promise();
console.log(attributes)
console.log(typeof attributes.Contact.LastUpdateTimestamp)
var agent_params = {
  InstanceId: 'place your instance id', /* required */
  UserId: attributes.Contact.AgentInfo.Id /* required */
  
};
const agent = await connect.describeUser(agent_params).promise();
let agent_username = "";
if(agent_username != null){
agent_username = agent.User.Username; 
}
console.log(agent) 
    var params = {
        TableName: process.env.TABLE,
        Item: {
            contactId: { S: event.Details.ContactData.ContactId},
            surveyId: { S: event.Details.ContactData.Attributes.surveyId },
            date: { S: attributes.Contact.LastUpdateTimestamp.toLocaleDateString()},
            time: { S: attributes.Contact.LastUpdateTimestamp.toLocaleTimeString()},
            agentname: {S: agent_username},
            ...surveyResults
        }
    }
    
    
    
    try {
        await ddb.putItem(params).promise();    // write the object to the DynamoDB table
    } catch (err) {
        console.log(err);
    }

    const response = {
        statusCode: 200,
        body: JSON.stringify('OK'),
    };
    
    return response;
};
```